# Get user agent in firebase functions callable

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

How do I get the user agent in firebase callable function?
I have tried using this:

```
functions.https.onCall((data, context) => { 
   console.log("agent", context.rawRequest.agent);
   // ....
  }
);
```

This logs the agent to be undefined.
How do I get the user agent in this callable?

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke a callable function, the client SDK doesn't provide a user agent string in the request.  It's not part of the [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).

If you want to receive a user agent string, you're going to have to provide one in the data object that you pass from the client.  It won't happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It's not written in the doc as mentioned above but then I saw that firebase is sending the user agent in the request header so I decided to dig deeper and found this:

```
functions.https.onCall((data, context) => { 
  const { ['user-agent']: userAgent } = context.rawRequest.headers;
  console.log('userAgent:', userAgent);
});
```